# How do I select from UNIQUE and COUNTIF by data in adjoined column?

Tags: google-sheets, unique, countif

Starting with this list of countries and dates:

| date | country |
| --- | --- |
| 01.04.2022 | Norway |
|  | Sweden |
|  | Norway |
| 02.03.2022 | Denmark |
| 03.03.2022 | Norway |

I want to pick the UNIQUE countries from the list but only those that have a date. I also want to run a COUNTIF on the countries but still only the ones that have a date.

Running a UNIQUE and COUNTIF wintout the dates will give this:

| UNIQUE(country) | COUNTIF(country;row) |
| --- | --- |
| Norway | 3 |
| Sweden | 1 |
| Denmark | 1 |

The result I need is only getting data from the rows that have a date, getting this result:

| country | count |
| --- | --- |
| Norway | 2 |
| Denmark | 1 |

How can I run UNIQUE and COUNTIF on a column based on the data in adjoined column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that QUERY() is designed for.  In a brand new tab in cell A1

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B,"select B,COUNT(B) where A is not null group by B order by COUNT(B) desc")
```

or if you're in some locales in western europe:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B;"select B,COUNT(B) where A is not null group by B order by COUNT(B) desc")
```